# Regular expression in R not recognising double escape character

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have the following text from which I would like to extract the questions between each double line break \n\n followed by the digit and the following double line break \n\n using a regular expression.

> \n\n1. Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?\n\n Currently, Albania is classified as a developing country by the United Nations Development\nProgramme, except for some UNDP programmes for which Albania is classified as a least developed\ncountry. Albania has applied for "least-developed country" status with UNDP and is awaiting a decision\non this matter.\n\nA.1(d) Division of Authority\n\n2. Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in\nAlbania: ministries and associated agencies at the central level, local and regional authorities.\n\n Please see Attachment I for a complete description of Albania's administrative structure.\n\nA.2 Economic Situation and Policies\n\n3. An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be\ninterested to learn more details about this programme.\n\n4. Is the "comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-\n1992) still in existence? If so, would you please describe what is still in effect.\n\n Albania's economic stabilization and reform programme is still in effect. With the achievement\nof basic stabilization, the emphasis of the programme has shifted to structural reforms. Nevertheless,\nthe government remains mindful of the importance of maintaining a stable macro-economic environment,\nand will continue its efforts in this direction.\n\n

I have tried to use the following code to extract the questions in R.

```
txt <- "\n\n1. Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?\n\n Currently, Albania is classified as a developing country by the United Nations Development\nProgramme, except for some UNDP programmes for which Albania is classified as a least developed\ncountry. Albania has applied for \"least-developed country\" status with UNDP and is awaiting a decision\non this matter.\n\nA.1(d) Division of Authority\n\n2. Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in\nAlbania: ministries and associated agencies at the central level, local and regional authorities.\n\n Please see Attachment I for a complete description of Albania's administrative structure.\n\nA.2 Economic Situation and Policies\n\n3. An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be\ninterested to learn more details about this programme.\n\n4. Is the \"comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-\n1992) still in existence? If so, would you please describe what is still in effect.\n\n Albania's economic stabilization and reform programme is still in effect. With the achievement\nof basic stabilization, the emphasis of the programme has shifted to structural reforms. Nevertheless,\nthe government remains mindful of the importance of maintaining a stable macro-economic environment,\nand will continue its efforts in this direction.\n\n"

questions <- str_match_all(txt,"(?<=[\n\n]\\d\\.\\s)(.*)(?=[\n\n])")
```

The output is the following:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]                                                                                     
[1,] "Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?"              
[2,] "Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in"  
[3,] "An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be"      
[4,] "Is the \"comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-"
     [,2]                                                                                     
[1,] "Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?"              
[2,] "Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in"  
[3,] "An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be"      
[4,] "Is the \"comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-"
```

However, I would like to extract the whole question and for example in the second question (see `questions[[1]][2,1]`) only the part of the question up to the single line break \n is extracted. How can I ensure that the regular expression in R extracts up to the occurrence of the double line break and not the single line break which is found in the middle of the question in the text?

My desired output is the following:

```
[[1]]
     [,1]                                                                                     
[1,] "Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?"              
[2,] "Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in\nAlbania: ministries and associated agencies at the central level, local and regional authorities."  
[3,] "An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be\ninterested to learn more details about this programme."      
[4,] "Is the \"comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-\n1992) still in existence? If so, would you please describe what is still in effect."
     [,2]                                                                                     
[1,] "Is Albania classified as a least developed country by the United Nations?"              
[2,] "Please provide further information regarding the existing administrative structure in\nAlbania: ministries and associated agencies at the central level, local and regional authorities."  
[3,] "An economic stabilization and reform programme was initiated in 1992. We would be\ninterested to learn more details about this programme."      
[4,] "Is the \"comprehensive economic stabilization and reform programme (established in mid-\n1992) still in existence? If so, would you please describe what is still in effect."
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Is `grep("^[0-9]",strsplit(txt, "\n\n")[[1]],value=TRUE)`enough?

Comment: Yes! That works perfectly and returns exactly what I was aiming for. Thank you very much for your quick help.